# Как правильно удалить динамический массив?

Tags: c++

Есть массив:
    int *mas = new int[100];

Как очистить его значения, т.е. сделать его пустым (каким он был до заполнения)?

Comment: До заполнения он _не был_ пустым, он содержал случайные значения. Чтобы обнулить массив, используйте `memset`. Но лучше перейдите на C++ и пользуйтесь `std::vector`'ом.

Comment: @VladD, я поработал с этим массивом заполнил его значениями, но потом мне нужно ещё раз с ним работать, но он уже заполнен другими значениями

Comment: `memset(mas, 0, sizeof(mas)*sizeof(int))` пробовали?

Comment: @KoVadim, да

Comment: и как результат? вернулось к начальному значению?

Comment: @KoVadim, нет....я попробовал for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
  delete[] mas[i];
Но выскакивает ошибка error C2541: delete: нельзя удалять объекты, не являющиеся указателями

Comment: Вы определитесь, что Вы хотите - удалить элементы массива, присвоить им какое то определенное значение (и не принципиально какое).

Comment: @KoVadim, удалить элементы массива

Comment: @barselona1002: число нельзя "удалить", оно всегда имеет какое-нибудь значение.

Comment: @barselona1002, удалить можно только весь массив. Нельзя удалить часть его элементов. 

Если надо удалить все элементы, то просто удаляйте массив.

Answer (score 2):

В языке С++ массив из 100 элементов типа `int` всегда содержит 100 элементов типа `int`. Он не бывает "пустым" или "не пустым". Невозможно "удалить" из массива его индивидуальные элементы или добавить новые элементы. Пока вы не уничтожите весь этот массив целиком вызовом `delete[]`, он будет существовать и содержать ровно 100 элементов типа `int`, т.е. "пустым" он никогда не был и не будет.

Что вы имеете в виду под "заполнением" - не совсем ясно. Массив в вашем примере изначально содержит *неинициализированные* объекты типа `int`. После того, как вы присвоите его элементам какие-то конкретные значения, вернуть его обратно к исходному неинициализированному состоянию будет уже невозможно - ничего подобного в С++ нет.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите оставить предыдушие значения, то нечего массив лопатить скопируйте его и изменяйте копию, а предыдущий останеться нетронутым и может быть использован далее. Функция memcpy(A, B, sizeof(B)) скопирует B в A.

Comment: мне не нужно оставлять предыдущие значения

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, когда ОЗУ освобождается, её не забивают нулями, а оставляют все как есть.

Когда прежде освобожденный участок озу выделяется для каких то нужд его значения всегда мусорные и юзающиеся прежде, а не нули. 
Попробуйте сами - запустите такой код

```
    int* i = new int;
    cout << *i;
```

Вам дадут мусорный инт, который получился из старых значений в памяти.

**Вывод: что-бы удалить массив достаточно освободить память для последующего выделения, а не вернуть ее состояние в изначальное.
И это делает оператор delete.
delete i;**